# Linq2Sql Where() clausule basing on the string of comma separated values

Tags: linq-to-sql

here's the scenario:

I have a table, let's say `Users`. Each user has the following columns: `ID` and `TypeID`.

I have a comma separated string with user `ID` numbers `"1,2,3,4,5"`.

I'm wondering, how can I achieve - via linq2sql - if I'm basing on that string, to check if that users has the same `TypeID` value ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Break out that list to a collection of values and use that collection to check if the `TypeID` is within it using `Contains()`.

```
var numbers = "1,2,3,4,5";
var typeIds = numbers.Split(',')
    .Select(n => Convert.ToInt32(n))
    .ToList();

var query =
    from user in db.Users
    where typeIds.Contains(user.TypeID)
    select user;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I didn't understand your question, as you've accepted Jeff's answer, or maybe you didn't understand his answer, as it doesn't do what I thought you wanted. What I understood was that your string is a list of IDs and you want to know if the users with these IDs all have the same TypeID. Here's a way of doing it (tested with LinqToObject, but should be translated well in LinqToSQL)

```
bool sameTypeID = (from user in users
                   where str.Split(',').Select(x => int.Parse(x)).Contains(user.ID)
                   group user.ID by user.TypeID into g
                   select g).Count() == 1;
```